# Cloud function query with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to query a firestore field (dropdown) 'Title'. I am using following code to get the total number of Title for a given user but i want to apply filter and get count only when Title == Game. Please help. How can i modify this function to set counter only when this condition is met.

Currently it is getting me number of title.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'


admin.initializeApp()

export const updateCharts = 
functions.firestore.document('users/{UserId}/count/{uid}')
.onWrite(async(change, _) => await updateStats(change))

async function updateStats (change: 
functions.Change<functions.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>){
const chartRating = change.after.ref.parent
let Title = 0


const docRefs = await chartRating.listDocuments()
for (const docRef of docRefs) {
    const snapshot = await docRef.get()
    const data = snapshot.data()
    if (data !== undefined) {
       
       
        Title++
    }
}

const restaurantRef = chartRating.parent!

console.log('{restaurantRef.path} now has ${Title}')
await restaurantRef.update({
    Title: Title,
    
})
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
let Title = 0
const docRefs = await chartRating.listDocuments()
for (const docRef of docRefs) {
    const snapshot = await docRef.get()
    const data = snapshot.data()
    if (data !== undefined) {
       Title++
    }
}
```

with

```
let title = (await chartRating.where('Title', '==', 'Game').get()).size;
```

replace the where statement with the condition you need.

Comment: I am receiving error- error TS1005: ',' expected. Please note it is typescript

Comment: Sorry about that. @Dharmaraj has corrected the function. Try with the corrected version (it has comma after the params of where statement).